# How to delete Proxy-Authorization Cache on Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, caching, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am building a "proxy client" extension for chrome and i have following scenario:

- Users can login to the extension and get a token from API. Tokens are valid for 2 hours.
- After login users can select a proxy server from a list and  that proxy is set with [chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) api.
- I am using Squid on proxy servers. When a user connects to a proxy server and lands on [onAuthRequired](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) i return email and token as authCredentials.

Chrome uses those credentials from cache until token is not valid anymore and proxy server responses "407, Proxy Authentication Required". Now the problem i am facing here is when i login with another username on same browser and connect to same proxy server it still sends old users credentials to the server because they are still valid. My question is how can delete chromes proxy auth cache so that it lands onAuthRequired again and i can return new users Credentials.

I tried to modify the response from proxy server to "407, Proxy Authentication Required" when user makes his first request over the proxy server to force a onAuthRequired but its not working. Chrome still uses cache and still returns credentials from old user to the proxy server.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having an issue caused by similar behaviour in Chrome ( just posted a question about it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469993/1330374 ). Seems like Chrome always wants to use the same auth details, and the `webRequest` events do not allow you to change or delete the `Proxy-Authorization` header. Likewise, when you cancel a request at `onAuthRequired`, something is remembered somewhere that prevents being able to trigger `onAuthRequired` from that server again.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338170/how-to-close-connection-with-proxy-server-in-chrome-extension) article. It has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hook up another event handler within the webRequest API in order to manipulate the http headers before Chrome takes on authentication?

E.g. onBeforeSendHeaders or onHeadersReceived

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome does not allow modifying "Proxy-" headers when using `onBeforeSendHeaders` or `onHeadersReceived`.