# webRequest onAuthRequired never catch 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-chrome-extension, webrequest, http-proxy

I'm trying to handle proxy authentication though chrome extensions.

On the one hand I have **chrome extension** (with all permissions established) that sends CONNECT request with **onAuthRequired handler** (background.js)

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    (details, callback) => {
        console.log('onAuthRequired', details) // <- this has never been displayed
        callback({
            authCredentials: {
                username: 'someid',
                password: 'somepwd'
            }
        })
    },{
        urls: ['<all_urls>']
    },
    ['asyncBlocking']
)

const config = {
    mode: "pac_script",
    pacScript: {
        data: "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {\n if (shExpMatch(host, \"*.pandora.com\"))\n return 'PROXY 127.0.0.1:8124';\n return 'DIRECT';\n }"
    }
}

chrome.proxy.settings.set({
    value: config,
    scope: 'regular',
}, function(){})
```

And on the other hand I have **NodeJS proxy server** that always sends the 407 status code as described in the [specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.2)

```
const http = require('http');

const proxy = http.createServer()
proxy.on('connect', (req, clientSocket, head) => {
    clientSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required')
    clientSocket.write('Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="Access to site"\r\n\n')
});

proxy.listen(8124)
```

Finally, the browser returns ERR_PROXY_AUTH_UNSUPPORTED which means that the status code is sent correcly...

The fact is **onAuthRequired is never triggered**, can anyone tell me why ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just in case, did you look in the [correct console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/accessing-console-and-devtools-of-extensions-background-js)?

Comment: Thanks for answering but yes

Comment: Try adding `, 'extraHeaders'` after `'asyncBlocking'`. If that won't help, it could be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Chrome aggressively caches the authentication calls to proxy servers. So you will only see your console.log call once per browser session (you need to restart Chrome completely, if you've got more than one profile open you'll need to close ALL instances of Chrome before the authentication cache is cleared).

I'm currently trying to figure out how to clear or empty said cache.

See also ([How to delete Proxy-Authorization Cache on Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869999/how-to-delete-proxy-authorization-cache-on-chrome-extension))